# Reporting line numbers from phantomjs

Tags: javascript, dom, phantomjs

Is it possible to get the line number where a particular DOM element is in the source from Phantomjs? I realize the DOM is different than the source, but given this http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html, it would appear it's possible.

I tried `onConsoleMessage` (using PhantomJS 2.0.0) but line number is `undefined` when trying to output to console.

Comment: Not sure what you mean... You can get a line number from source code in phantoms by throwing and [parsing the stack trace on the error object](https://github.com/mantoni/brout.js/blob/master/lib/brout.js#L74).  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Let's say I get hold of some DOM node. Is it possible to get the line number? Are you saying in order to get the line number throw and catch an error when trying to get the node in order to parse the stacktrace to get the line nu?

Comment: What do you mean by line number?

Comment: Given a DOM node, what line number it appears in the source code. I guess not really because the DOM is not the same as the source and DOM nodes can be inserted after page load of course. But I'm curious why the PhantomJS docs would suggest this is possible from the `onConsoleMessage` callback.

Comment: The line number they have in mind is the line number of the console.log statement in the source code.